# #Question Flutter 1: How can i achieve this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api

i want to pass a listDevice from screen to screen and i get no data on the next screen ?
What syntax error am I getting?
Screen 1: Data Transfer

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'deviceInformation', arguments: listDevice);
```

Screen 2:receive data

```
final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Data;
```

Comment: i print listDevice is 'null'

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with Navigator.pushNamed(context, **'/deviceInformation'**, arguments: listDevice);

Comment: i tried and got 'No route defined for /deviceInformation'

Comment: You can see more of my code here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PoKzQpOjw6Z8NTTu4qJNOpy2bu7OBgolwoc1dXwvP-s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: for no route define error
please make sure you have defined the route in the material app like 
this one
MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    ''/deviceInformation'': (context) =>
        const YourExtractArgumentsScreen(),
  },
)

Comment: remove the const if not needed.

Comment: ModalRoute.of(context) is null,null, how can fix